# Iteration of loop should produce 16 names not 4

Tags: php

I have the loop below which iterates 4 times. Within this look is another which defines my group names.  I would like to produce the output

```
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
....
Group 15
Group 16
```

instead of what I currently get

```
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
Group 04
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
Group 04 
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
Group 04
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
Group 04
```

Code

```
foreach ($largegroups as $key => $users) { // loops 4 times
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        $num = sprintf("%02d", $i);
        $groupname = 'Group ' . $num;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're resetting $i at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: You are always starting your inner `for` loop from 1 to 4, that why you get results from 1 to 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a counter to the outer loop, and multiply that by 4 before adding `$i` to get the group number. For example:

```
$g = 0;
foreach ($largegroups as $key => $users) { // loops 4 times
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        $num = sprintf("%02d", $g * 4 + $i);
        $groupname = 'Group ' . $num;
    }
    $g++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should declare and use a counter to calculate the correct number of a group. For example:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($largegroups as $key => $users) { // loops 4 times
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
        $counter++;
        $groupname = sprintf("Group %02d", $counter);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use [`range()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function to generate group numbers and avoiding of nested loops. For example:

```
$count = count($largegroups) * 4;
foreach (range(1, $count) as $number) {
    $groupname = sprintf(" Group %02d", $number);
}
```

Comment: Your second solution `range()` is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
Two modifications:
```

1) Add a counter variable which iterates every time inner loop iterates. That is 4 X 4 = 16 times. Increment the counter at the beginning of inner loop. So that we start from `1` to end `16` instead of `0` to `15`.

2) Add `str_pad()` function that will add leading `0` for counters less than 10. So `Group 1` would become `Group 01`.

```
<?php 
$largegroups = ['','','',''];
$c = 0;
foreach ($largegroups as $key => $users) { // loops 4 times
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
  ++$c;
  $c = str_pad($c, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo "<br/>".$groupname = 'Group ' . $c;
 }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Group 01
Group 02
Group 03
Group 04
Group 05
Group 06
Group 07
Group 08
Group 09
Group 10
Group 11
Group 12
Group 13
Group 14
Group 15
Group 16
```

[Working Example:](https://3v4l.org/aUDd2)